# Is it a good practice to write UnitTests for System.NotImplementedException/System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I am implementing set of interfaces from third party library. I don't want to support all the features defined in the interfaces, so I´m throwing `System.NotImplementedException` / `System.NotSupportedException` for the not supported features.

Should I write Unit-tests for the piece of code which throws the exception?
Is it ok if I write tests?

Comment: `NotSupportedException` usually implies "this implementation will never support this feature", so a UT to document this fact seems appropriate.  `NotImplementedException` usually means "I haven't got round to implementing it yet", so I wouldn't have thought you'd want a UT that expects this exception.

Comment: "I don't want to support all the features defined in the interfaces" Then you shouldn´t implement it. There´s no use in implementing an interface only patially.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - there are situations in which it's appropriate to implement an interface partially (and usually throw `NotSupportedException` where relevant.  For example, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` implements `ICollection<T>.Add` by throwing `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: @Joe Only because they exist does not mean it´s a good idea to do so. I allways felt `IRadonlyCollection.Add` strange.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - it would be even stranger, and less usable, if `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` didn't implement `ICollection<T>`. The documentation for `NotSupportedException` gives another example: "You are implementing a general-purpose interface, and number of the methods have no meaningful implementation. For example, if you are creating a date and time type that implements the IConvertible interface, you would throw a NotSupportedException exception for most of the conversions."

Comment: As TDD experience, I should write the unit test first, at that time, all functions throw `NotImplementedException` so in my opinion, I'd like to use `NotSupportedException`

Answer (score 1):

It is ok to write unit tests checking for `NotSupportedExceptions` in partial interface implementations. By doing so you'll document that this is the desired behaviour of the implementation.
If someone will implement this method later, he has to adjust the unit test and has to -at least- think about, if this is the new desired system behaviour.